# Error while Creating Reagct app using npx create react app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, npx

ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -4077
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\vishudh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-10-31T11_06_57_455Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.

i tried all npm install -g command but it did not worked .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.